# How to customise the color on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
  proc_bars <- ggplot(data, mapping=aes(ymin=0, ymax=1,
                                                xmin=start_min, xmax=stop_min,
                                                fill=as.factor(category),
                                                colour=color #column in data
                                                ))
```

How to change the color from default pink and light blue?

The color is the column in data which saved as the color code as string that I want to use for the chart like #FFFF00 but it failed with the above code to change the color, any one knows why? The chart expected is the a segmented bar chart horizantally which shows each categories start and stop time.

dataframe:

```
library(ggplot2)
category <- c('task1', 'task2', 'task2','task1','task1')
start_min <- c(0, 0, 16, 45, 40)
stop_min <- c(14.9,18.8,17.5,65.5, 70)
color <- c('#FFFF00','#3581B8','#3581B8','#FFFF00', '#FFFF00')
data <- data.frame(category,start_min,stop_min, color)
```

Comment: Hi, please share a reproducible sample of your data set with `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: Try with `+ scale_color_identity()`. If you want a legend do ´+ scale_color_identity(guide = guide_legend())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Data

```
category <- c('task1', 'task2', 'task2','task1','task1')
start_min <- c(0, 0, 16, 45, 40)
stop_min <- c(14.9,18.8,17.5,65.5, 70)
color <- c('#FFFF00','#3581B8','#3581B8','#FFFF00', '#FFFF00')
data <- data.frame(category,start_min,stop_min, color)
```

### Plot code

You need to use your color vector in `scale_`, in the example below I use the aesthetic `color`, and then define the colors later in `scale_colour_manual`

```
data %>% 
   ggplot(mapping=aes(
      start_min,
      stop_min,
      colour=as.factor(category)
   ))+
   geom_point(size = 8)+
   scale_colour_manual(values = color)
```

### Output

[image]